# Getting motherboard sensor values using OpenHardwareMonitor in c#

Tags: c#, hardware, sensors, motherboard, openhardwaremonitor

Using the Computer class I successfully retrieved CPU sensor values.
However, when it comes to Mainboard, sensor values are not shown every time I run the application. In the most cases the information is not shown, but sometimes it is.
What could be the reason that motherboard sensor values are not retrieved every time I run the application?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Lifetime;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public sealed class OpenHardwareMonitor { }
        public class UpdateVisitor : IVisitor
        {
            public void VisitComputer(IComputer computer)
            {
                computer.Traverse(this);
            }
            public void VisitHardware(IHardware hardware)
            {
                hardware.Update();
                foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardware.SubHardware) subHardware.Accept(this);


            }
            public void VisitSensor(ISensor sensor) { }
            public void VisitParameter(IParameter parameter) { }
        }
        static void GetSystemInfo()
        {
            UpdateVisitor updateVisitor = new UpdateVisitor();
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            computer.Open();
            computer.CPUEnabled = true;
            computer.MainboardEnabled = true;
            computer.RAMEnabled = true;
            computer.FanControllerEnabled = true;
            computer.Accept(updateVisitor);

            for (int i = 0; i < computer.Hardware.Length; i++)
            {
                if (computer.Hardware[i].HardwareType == HardwareType.Mainboard)
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < computer.Hardware[i].Sensors.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                            Console.WriteLine(computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].Name + ":" + computer.Hardware[i].Sensors[j].Value.ToString() + "\r");
                    }
                }
            }
            computer.Close();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetSystemInfo();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried running it on other PCs but the same thing happens, it sometimes work but usually it doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a nuget package for OpenHardwareMonitor or did you add the [source project](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor) to your solution?

Comment: Hello, yes I installed OpenHardwareMonitor through nuget package and ran application as administrator